# VB Mismatch Error

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I keep getting a mismatch error for this line:

```
UPDATE tblLunchTime SET [End] = '06/28/2010 9:41:34 AM' WHERE Start = '06/28/2010 9:41:31 AM'
```

Does anyone know why?

EDIT: Rest of the code added.

```
'Save end time in database.
Dim strValuesQuery As String

strValuesQuery = _
    "UPDATE tblLunchTime " & _
    "SET [End] = '" & Now & "' " & _
    "WHERE Start = '" & StartTime & "' "

'Execute Query.
DoCmd.RunSQL strValuesQuery
```

Comment: can you post the code that is used to execute that statement....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding the pound symbol to my variable in order to allow it to be formatted in the way needed:

```
strValuesQuery = _
    "UPDATE tblLunchTime " & _
    "SET EndTime = #" & Now & "# " & _
    "WHERE StartTime = #" & StartTime & "#"
```

Comment: # is the delimiter for dates in Jet/ACE SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing this query to SqlServer, oracle ?

Is same language at client side and server side ?

Using date To String and String to date needs a specific format conversion.

For oracle:  EndTime = to_date('2010/01/05','yyyy/mm/dd')

this avoids language mismatch.

I use always parameters.

"UPDATE tblLunchTime SET EndTime = ? WHERE StartTime = ?"   - For OleDb

Parameters avoid some errors, and also improve performance (Server caches cursors).